# Backward Kolmogorov equation for simple markov process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

The following exercise is from a course on SDE's and I am a bit stumped. Consider the process.

$dX_t=\lambda\left(\xi-X_t \right)dt+\gamma\sqrt{|X_t|}dB_t$

$\lambda,\xi,\gamma>0$

Find $\mathbb{P}^{X_t=x}\left( X_t>2\right)$.

Now I would start by finding transition probabilities $p(t\rightarrow T,x\rightarrow X_T)$ in the backwards kolmogorov equation $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t }+Lp=0$, where $L$ is the generator for the diffusion. How would I then find the relevant area in the state space? And how to find the solution to the kolmogorov equation for these parameters?

Comment: Can this be explicitly calculated? In any case, $X$ can be transformed into a squared Bessel process, which is extensively studied.

Comment: I was looking at another post, which had a link to the following paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.852.120&rep=rep1&type=pdf. In page 4, you can find the expression for the transition density of a CIR process. It should be possible to verify that it satisfies the Kolmogorov equations.

Comment: That is a great article, love it when it is written so clearly, thank you